# React browserhistory.push not working for the first time

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I am loading page with url parameter and then resetting to root url with browserhistroy.push(), first time it is not working and when I see logs the props.param shows the same old url pathname. Second time when again I clicked it is working as expected. 
Note: Using React with redux, using "react-router".
Code: 
route.js

```js
{
      path: '/:menuitem',
      name: 'Products',
      getComponent(nextState, cb) {
        const importModules = Promise.all([
          import('views/Products/modules/reducer'),
          import('views/Products/modules/sagas'),
          import('views/Products'),
        ]);

        const renderRoute = loadModule(cb);

        importModules.then(([reducer, sagas, component]) => {
          injectReducer('search', reducer.default);
          injectSagas(sagas.default);
          renderRoute(component);
        });
        importModules.catch(errorLoading);
      },
    },
```

In component: setting param/url

```js
 var urlname = options[secIndex][itemIndex].name;
      urlname = urlname.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
      console.log(urlname);
      browserHistory.push('/'+urlname);
      this.props.leftStripActions.onFilterByLens(options[secIndex][itemIndex]);
```

Resetting to root:
 browserHistory.push('/'); [This is not working for first time`enter code here`]

Any help would great appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
use => this.props.history.push(url)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.